# Local de dowload - Selenium Firefox + Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Não consigo mudar o local padrão de download no Firefox usando selenium
o código está assim:

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
fp.set_preference('browser.download.dir', r'C:\Users\Martini\Documents')

fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/zip")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip")

firefox = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

Já testei em outros locais, tentei tirar o r e deixas as \, mas nada funcionou. 
Todos os downloads vão para a pasta padrão , na pasta Downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código parece correto, talvez o tipo do arquivo baixado talvez não está vindo com o MimeType do tipo "application/zip".
Veja neste site todos os [MIME Types existentes](https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html).

Solução: 
Você pode colocar mais Mimetypes na mesma linha, dependendo da configuração do servidor pode estar vindo como octet-stream.

Tente mudar a linha conforme abaixo, veja se resolve o problema:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip;application/octet-stream;application/x-gzip")
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!